# Transaction sent and confirmed but execution got reverted on Mumbai testnet

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, contract-invocation, ethers.js

I cannot figure out why the transaction is getting reverted by Mumbai testnet.
It works fine in Remix EVM and Hardhat testsuite but is getting reverted on `mumbai` and `rinkeby` networks, I haven't tested other EVM networks but I think result would be the same.

This is the contract function I'm calling:

```
    function addAllPotentialWinnings(
        uint256 _eventNumber,
        uint256[][] memory _potentialWinnings,
        uint256[] memory _chainsList,
        address[] memory _winnersList
    ) public onlyOwner {
        winnersList[_eventNumber] = _winnersList;
        updateChains(_eventNumber, _chainsList);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _winnersList.length; i++) {
            updatePotentialWinnings(_eventNumber,_winnersList[i],_potentialWinnings[i]);}}
```

I provide it with with the data that fits the proposed schema. But the execution is reverted. Here is the exact data I provided to the execution:

```
(0, [[3700000000000, 617288888888888]],[4,80001],["0xE57EF8ba635f6659685d1A84c04c112D63619Ee5"])
```

[Reverted transaction on blockexplorer](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xbb383936438b3b3488198a880307598afcfc8f3dbee037bfcaa43b45142724aa) and the  [verified contract](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x89aaa42ab993eab41f3292538ea5cf2f685209fc#code) I'm working with.

I call the transaction from the front end with `ethers.js` and after making the call `metamask` confirmation window pops up where I confirm the transaction but later (~15-20s) after the transaction is mined I get the metamask error in a pop up.

Other state changing transactions are going through. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not resolve this problem directly - had to completely change the data structure of the contract to allow for this functionality.